# Assembly stack is storing unknown elements. Unsure of the source

Tags: assembly, mips

The goal was to make a program that would read in the array of numbers below and print it in reverse. For whatever reason i keep getting this as the output:

> Given Array of Integer Numbers are = 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25
>   27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49 51 53 55 57 59 1766260768
>   544105846 1634890305 1718558841 1953384736 1919248229 1836404256
>   1936876898 1701994784 2112800 1376389642 1919252069 543450483
>   1634890305 1718558841 1953384736 1919248229 1968054387 1919246957
>   1918967923 540876901
>
> Reversed Array of Integers Numbers are = 540876901 1918967923
>   1919246957 1968054387 1919248229 1953384736 1718558841 1634890305
>   543450483 1919252069 1376389642 2112800 1701994784 1936876898
>   1836404256 1919248229 1953384736 1718558841 1634890305 544105846
>   1766260768
>
> 59 57 55 53 51 49 47 45 43 41 39 37 35 33 31 29 27 25 23 21 19 17 15
>   13 11 9 7 5 3 1
>
> 4 2147481709 2147481686 2147481673 2147481666

Can someone please clarify to me why I am getting these random numbers? I realize it must be a string that is being printed as an integer but I don't know where its coming from.

The code is below:

```
.data

array: .word 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59

space: .asciiz" "

p1: .asciiz "Given Array of Integer Numbers are = "

p2: .asciiz "\n\n\nReversed Array of Integers Numbers are = "


.text

.globl main

main:

la $a0, p1
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $t0, 0

loop1:

lw $a0, array($t0)

beqz $a0, end

sub $sp, $sp, 4

sw $a0, ($sp) 

addi $t0, $t0, 4

li $v0, 1
syscall

la $a0, space
li $v0, 4
syscall


j loop1


end:

la $a0, p2

li $v0, 4

syscall


loop2:

lw $a0, ($sp)

beqz $a0, end2

addi $sp, $sp, 4


li $v0, 1

syscall

la $a0, space

li $v0, 4

syscall


j loop2

end2:

li $v0, 10

syscall
```

Comment: Your code expects a zero terminator but you have not supplied it. Put a `, 0` at the end of your array. Note that the reversed array also needs to be zero terminated (which is the beginning in that case) but you don't do that either.

Comment: For future questions please tag your questions with the appropriate CPU/assembler-specific tag as well (as suggested by the [assembly] tag).

Comment: @Jester I was under the impression that beqz could also be used as a null terminator(That is to say, if the next data item to be loaded is null, then branch).

Comment: That is correct. But you do not have a zero data defined. Neither in the original array nor in the reversed case. Hence both your loops will process excess memory until they happen to find a zero. Use your debugger/simulator to single step the code and see what it is doing.